# How to tell C# to omit creation of attributes that are default during serialization?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class that is serialized to a XML file. There are several properties that are rarely used but always created. If I delete them within the XML the deserialization still works, because they have the default value.

These unnecessary (bool) attributes make the XML harder to read.

Can I somehow tell C# to omit elements or attributes that still have default value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Specify the [DefaultValueAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx), and if the value matches, it won't be output.

Comment: ´[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]´ did it for bool values - Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

Rowland has the answer for simple values. For more complex scenarios, you can add a method called `public bool ShouldSerializeFoo()` (for property `Foo`) - it it returns `false`, it won't get serialized.

Comment: I would just like to mention the EditorBrowsableAttribute which can be used to prevent auxiliary members like these from appearing in IntelliSense.

Comment: Instead of ShouldSerializeFoo(), a bool FooSpecified Property can also be used.

Comment: If you go with the *Specified patter, you need to remember to mark it [XmlIgnore], IIRC

Answer (score -1):

Use the XMLIgnore() Attribute to mark a property to be ingnored in Serialization / Deserialization.

Comment: No, that will **alays** exclude it; the question is to exclude it when it has the default value.

Comment: I think OP wants to just ignore properties that have a default value. Your solution would cause properties to always be ignored.